# Detecting duplicate values in certain indexes in a list of lists

Tags: python, list, indexing

I'm using a list of lists (to resemble a puzzle) and trying to write a function that will return 'False' if there's at least one duplicate values in the same index as another list (which can be seen as columns, visually) (and True if otherwise). For example:

```
List = [[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
          [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
          [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
          [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
          [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]]
```

should return 'True' since nothing repeats
but:

```
List = [[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
          [ 6,  2,  8,  9, 10],
          [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
          [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
          [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]]
```

should return "False" since there is a value of "2" in the list1 of index[1] and value of "2" in list2 with the index of [1] as well.

the way I wrote the function is below

```
def check_columns_valid(list):

  for i in range(len(list)):
     if i[0] == i[5]  == i[10] ==  i[15] == i[20]:
        return False
     elif i[1] == i[6] == i[11] == i[16] == i[21]:
        return False
     elif i[2] == i[7] == i[12] == i[17] == i[22]:
        return False
     elif i[3] == i[8] == i[13] == i[18] == i[23]:
        return False
     elif i[4] == i[9] == i[14] == i[19] == i[24]:
        return False
   return True
```

I was trying to check if certain indexes equaled each other but it may be that my code will only return 'False' if ALL indexes equal each other and I only need at least one. And I'm also unsure if this is way of doing it is even valid at all. I don't know if I'm skipping steps.

Comment: Did you test it? Try it out with some sample data. Finding a specific issue will help people debug it.

Comment: When you write  i[0] == i[5]  == i[10] ==  i[15] == i[20] this means they ALL equal each other. If you write i[0] == i[5] or i[0] == i[10] or ... you'll get what you want, but there are much better ways to solve this.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `zip` and sets to help with this.

```
def check_columns_valid(puzzle):
    # Iterate over the puzzle one column at a time.
    for column in zip(*puzzle):
        # Get all of the unique values in the column.
        uniques = set(column)
        if len(uniques) != len(column):
            # If the number of unique values isn't the same as the
            # number of values, return False.
            return False

    return True
```

Or, if you're a fan of one-liners, all of this can be reduced to:

```
def check_columns_valid(puzzle):
    return all(len(x) == len(set(x)) for x in zip(*puzzle))
```

Depending on the size of `puzzle`, if you're using Python 2.x, you probably want to considering using `izip` (`from itertools import izip`) rather than `zip`.

Answer (score 1):

The following would work:

```
puzzle = [[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
      [ 6,  2,  8,  9, 10],
      [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
      [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
      [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]]

print sum(len(set(x)) for x in zip(*puzzle)) < 25
```

This will display `True`.

This works by taking the list of rows and converting it into a list of columns by using `zip(*puzzle)`. From here it creates a set from each column. If the size of the set is less than 5, then two items must be the same. So as you have 5 x 5, if the total is less than 25 then items must match somewhere.

---

And as a function:

```
def check_columns_valid(puzzle):
    return sum(len(set(x)) for x in zip(*puzzle)) < 25
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are great, and demonstrate how to use Python's large library of built-in functions to your advantage.  Less code is better!

However, if you'd like to see an answer that does it "the hard way", for educational purposes:

```
def check_columns_valid(puzzle):
    # check each item against later items in the same column
    for row in range(0, len(puzzle)):
        for column in range(0, len(puzzle[0])):
            if puzzle[row][column] in [puzzle[r][column] for r in range(row+1, 5)]:
                return False
```